# Error while migrating mysql database from staging environment to live for wordpress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

i have three environments, Local , Staging and Live and i am using git for version control . when Migrating the database from local to staging the migration happens with no error at all. but when migrating from staging to live there is a error in import step on phpmyadmin saying
[image]

Comment: review your `wp_options` table. You have duplicate IDs.

Comment: on staging there are no duplicate entries but when migrating this same database to live environment there i see duplicate entry for 0 value

Comment: you need clean those out.